# How do you run lite-server as a Windows service?

Tags: lite-server, nssm

I am trying to set up `lite-server` as a Windows service so that it starts automatically when the machine starts. I am trying to do this via [NSSM](https://nssm.cc/).

I install as follows:

```
nssm install <servicename> lite-server
```

Then, since I see it complaining in the event viewer about the directory it's running from, I add this:

```
nssm set <servicename> AppDirectory <serviceDirectory>
```

If I run `lite-server` directly from the command line it works.

However, if I start the Windows service installed as above, it fails, and in the event viewer I get:

> Failed to start service .  Program lite-server couldn't be launched. CreateProcess() failed: The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried:

1. Adding the path to %APPDATA%\npm to the system path to make sure `lite-server` can be found.
2. Installing the service under my own username.

It didn't work. What do I need to do to run `lite-server` as a Windows service?

Comment: I also need to set up lite-server as a service and still with no success....

Answer (score 0):

please try with same config

path: `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Roaming\npm\lite-server.cmd`

startup directory : `bs-config.json config file path`

screenshot like this

[image]